# Supported browsers for Selenium2 (WebDriver)

Tags: java, browser, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

Does anyone know what browsers are supported by WebDriver?

The official documents doesn't explicitly state it yet urging us to work with Selenium2.0 instead of 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Since Selenium has merged with WebDriver, there are a number of specific drivers that have been developed. If you look at the [javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) for the WebDriver interface you can see them. I count so far (in no particular order):

- [Chrome](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html)
- [Android](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/android/AndroidDriver.html)
- [iPhone](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/iphone/IPhoneDriver.html) (iOS?)
- [Firefox](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html)
- [Internet Explorer](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html)
- [Opera](https://github.com/operasoftware/operadriver) (on github, thanks [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119159/martin))

This list will no doubt change as more browsers become supported.

Comment: Internet Explorer support focuses mainly on IE 9.

Comment: "The InternetExplorerDriver is a standalone server which implements WebDriver's wire protocol. This driver has been tested with IE 6, 7, 8 and 9 on appropriate combinations of XP, Vista and Windows 7."
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Answer (score 0):

- Chrome Driver
- Firefox Driver
- Internet Explorer driver
- HtmlUnit driver
- Opera driver
- iPhone driver
- Android driver
- Safari also will be available by year’s end